# Nlog logs location overwritten by code still logging happening at config location

Tags: c#, nlog

NLog version - 4.4.3

Platform - .Net 4.5.2

Current NLog config -

```xml
<nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <variable name="layout" value="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${threadid}|${logger}|${message}" />
  <variable name="logLocation" value="logs" />
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${layout}" />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${layout}" />
    <target name="logfile" 
            xsi:type="File" 
            fileName="${logLocation}\${processname}.log" 
            archiveFileName="${logLocation}\\${processname}.{###}.log" 
            archiveEvery="Day" 
            archiveAboveSize="2048000" 
            archiveNumbering="Rolling" 
            maxArchiveFiles="10" 
            concurrentWrites="false" 
            keepFileOpen="false" 
            layout="${layout}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debugger" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Code to override location

```
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<AsyncTargetWrapper>("logfile").WrappedTarget;
target.FileName = $@"..\..\..\..\logs\Foobar.log";
```

- What is the current result?
  When application/service starts it writes to overwritten location, but sometimes (not sure of scenario - *maybe* rollover) it start writing to config location.
- What is the expected result?
  Logs should always be written to overwritten location.
- Did you checked the [Internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging)?
  No
- Please post full exception details (message, stacktrace, inner exceptions)
  No Exception
- Are there any workarounds? yes/no
  Restart service/application.
- Is there a version in which it did work?
   
  No idea. This is the version we started with and sticking to.
- Can you help us by writing an unit test?
  Unit tests won't help as it is an intermittent scenario.

Comment: Opened on Github - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have auto reload (`<nlog autoReload="true”`) enabled, so if it needs to reload (after sleep or change in config), you will lose the changes made in code.

The solution it so disable autoreload, or set the change after reload again. See code example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UpdateNLogConfig();

    LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded += LogManager_ConfigurationReloaded;

    log.Info("Entering Application.");

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
    Console.Read();
}


private static void LogManager_ConfigurationReloaded(object sender, LoggingConfigurationReloadedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateNLogConfig();
}

private static void UpdateNLogConfig()
{
    //note: don't set  LogManager.Configuration because that will overwrite the nlog.config settings
    var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<AsyncTargetWrapper>("logfile").WrappedTarget;
    target.FileName = $@"..\..\..\..\logs\Foobar.log";   
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```

See also [Combine XML config with C# config · NLog/NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Combine-XML-config-with-C%23-config)

Comment: +1 Thanks Julian. I'll go with former option - removing `autoreload` from config - as this will fix existing apps w/o changing code. And I'll accept this as an answer pretty soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing target lookup, and modifying target properties directly. Then I suggest making use of the NLog Layout Logic.

```
<nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="logfile" 
            xsi:type="File" 
            fileName="${gdc:item=logFile:whenEmpty=log/${processname}.log}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And then just assign the logLocation:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logFile", $@"..\..\..\..\logs\Foobar.log");
```

Using GDC will also works very well with `autoReload=true` and no need to call `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()`.